# Fail to retrieve data from database and error "Trying to get property num_rows of non-object"

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working on a project to retrieve the login details from the database to authenticate users.

However, I couldn't get the authentication part, even though the username and password are in the database, there is a problem retrieving them. In addition, I have gotten the error "Trying to get property num_rows of non-object". Kindly advise what is non-object.

Thank you in advance!

Below is a snippet of my code :

```
    <?php //login.php
include "dbconnect.php";
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
  // if the user has just tried to log in
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

$password = md5($password);
  $query = 'select * from users'
           ."where username='$username' "
           ." and password='$password'";

//echo "<br>" .$query. "<br>";
  $result = $dbcnx->query($query);
  if ($result->num_rows >0 )
  {
    // if they are in the database register the user id
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
  }


  $dbcnx->close();
}
?>
```

---

```
 <?php
@$dbcnx = new mysqli('localhost','root','','kimbae');

if ($dbcnx->connect_error){
    echo "Database is not online";
    exit;

    }

if (!$dbcnx->select_db ("kimbae"))
    exit("<p>Unable to locate the kimbae database</p>");
?>
```

Comment: `$result` is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

The `Trying to get property num_rows of non-object` error that you mention is related to `$result` not receiving the proper query result. You could `echo $result;` to see what's there. Will probably be empty or null.

Assuming `$dbcnx` exists and is correct, the only error I noticed is that your query string is missing a space on the second line, which creates an invalid SQL query. It should be like this:

```
$query = 'select * from users'
       ." where username='$username' "
       ." and password='$password'";
```

If that doesn't work, please post the code you have inside **dbconnect.php** as well.

*PS.: Even though I am not an expert in PHP, you should probably look into a better/safer way to do authentication. Maybe go with a framework or something like that.*

*PS 2.: This has nothing do to with javascript, so wrong TAG there :)*

Comment: Instead of echo $result, you should use print_r or var_dump. And i would suggest at least filter user input (because of sql inject).

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Will look into another method for authentication but was taught to use this for a project. I have added the dbconnect code into the question.

Comment: @Nimer good point, print_r or var_dump would be better. I didn't mention sql injection because of the advice to chage the auth method. But that's a valid thing to keep in mind.

Comment: @Android_Newbie did you try to add the space in the query? Are you having the same issue after the change?

Comment: I realised the issue was with the sql file, I declared the char count wrongly! Thanks for the help regardless! :)

Comment: Glad you found the problem! :)